# Magento layout.xml responsive condition

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, ce-1.9.0.1, rwd

is there any way in magento to use this method `method="unsetChild"` in `layout.xml` file with some conditions? I need to unsetChild if the window width is less than 760px?

```
 <action  method="unsetChild" ><name>catalog.topnav</name></action>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the layout is built server side, you should use CSS media queries instead to hide the navigation with `display:none`.

Comment: thank you I know this? but i want to use two different top menu's for desktop and mobile, one is an extension and one is the default magento menu. If both are enabled i don;t have the same results, so i need to unset one, foud something like this but is not work: <action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.topnav</name><params>media="only screen and (min-width: 767px)"</params></action>

Comment: Not possible with layout, you have to render both menus and use CSS to decide which is shown.

Comment: if do this one of the menu will not work

Comment: i just send to you my website address in your info@s.... email, please take a look in the desktop mode then resize your browser for mobile, in the mobile mode if i don;t use the unset the categories won't display